# Activate iPhone with unactivated SIM

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to activate an iPhone with an inactive SIM? (T-Mobile sells SIM cards for $0.99; could I get one of those and use it to activate an iPhone?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, just as long as a SIM card is in there, you can use it to activate an iPhone. You won't get any cell service, but you could use it on Wi-Fi.